# Amazon error: Invalid ProductType value for SKU

Tags: amazon-mws

I am new to `Amazon MWS API`. I am working on Product feed and having problem with `SKU`. My scenario is when `SKU` length is less than 12 then add "WH" string with `SKU` value. For example if `SKU` is 920126, it will become WH920126.
When i get Amazon feed submission result, i get error message:

```
 Invalid ProductType value for SKU: [WH920126].
```

According to the `Amazon` data definitions, `SKU` is an alphanumeric string; 1 character minimum in length and 40 characters maximum in length.

Any idea what is wrong with it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I got a same error..

I figured out the problem is if you delete any product from amazon you cannot upload product with same SKU which you deleted for another 24hours..

So it keeps saying Invalid ProductType value for SKU in my case.

Let Assume you uploaded a product successfully with SKU 4001 and deleted it for some reason (Using seller account). You cannot upload product with SKU 4001 for next 24 Hours. So try using different SKU then you might upload a product to amazon successfully.

Hope this helps.. Please let me know if any other reasons too..